# How to pass html code in jqm calendar summary

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have used jqm calendar for events list. Its showing perfect and showing list according to date. but now I want to link events list to their detail page so I need to pass html code means summary as a link so when list show below the calendar its can be likable and when I click it redirect to its detail page. below are my code

`{"summary": <a href="/detail/12">Event Name</a>',
                        "begin": new Date(2015,8,24 ),
                        "end": new Date(2015,8,24)}` 
    but its showing me title as it as above not making it linkable title.

please sugggest

Comment: please add more code, or even better create a jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for this you can pass url in url key. see below code:-

`{"summary": "Test Event name here",
"url":"your url here",
"begin": new Date(2015,8,24 ),
"end": new Date(2015,8,24)
}`